# Why does my date picker only pick the current date?

Tags: html

I've added a date picker for users to pick a date to enter what foods they've had for that day.

When testing this out, whatever date I pick, only todays date gets stored into my SQL database.

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
    //session_start();

    // connect to database
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password','registration');


if (ISSET($_POST['submit_btn'])) {

    session_start();
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $breakfast = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['breakfast']);
    $lunch = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['lunch']);
    $dinner = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['dinner']);
    $snack = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['snack']);
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

     $query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO food_diary
                      (date,breakfast,lunch,dinner,snack,userid)
                      VALUES('".$date."', '".$breakfast."', '".$lunch."', '".$dinner."','".$snack."', '".$userid."')");
}


?>
```

Comment: you are either storing the default date in DB or you are not fetching the correct value.

Comment: Can you provide more code or the datepicker used?

Comment: We are not mind readers, you have to provide some more context for anyone to be able to help

Comment: I've added the PHP code

Comment: `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` – why would this pick up the date that was selected in the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = $_POST['calender_date'];
```

and now it will save the user selected date.

Comment: It stores the date as 0000-00-00 now

Comment: reply here with the form field, coz I am sure its mismatch of field name. ah you need to convert to mySQL date format which is Y-m-d

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the form field?